# How to persist a selection in Kendo-Grid row click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo-grid in which I added a checkbox column. On select of checkbox I add the row details in a seperate variable and on deselect I remove the row data from the variable.

HTML:

```
<kendo-grid data=[data].... (selectionChange)="onRowSelectionChange($event)"></kendo-grid>
```

Typescript:

```
onRowSelectionChange(event:any){
if(event.selectedRows.length >0){
 this.selectedRowData.push(event.selectedRows[0].items)
}
else if(event.deselectedRows.length > 0) {
this.selectedRowData.pop()
}
}
```

This functionality seems to be working fine if and if I select and deselect from checkbox column. However say if I click on some other column name then all the selections become unchecked and the checkbox of that particular row is selected and all others become deselected but my variable(selectedRows) still contains the selected element data. How can I solve this issue